# apt-get command problem

Tags: 12.04, apt

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit** in hp pavilion dv6 laptop (AMD Processor) after upgrade and reboot, the desktop doesn't start and at cui (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>). When I try to login to my user and following error shows:

```
apt-config :/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib.so.6:version 'GLIBC_2.17' NOT FOUND (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

when I type `sudo apt-get` command same error shows up and `apt-get` command doesn't work. All I have is character user interface.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the error message above correctly ? Isn't it `libc.so.6` that was printed on your screen ?

Comment: the error as shown is libstdc++.so.6

Comment: could you run `ldd /usr/bin/apt-config` and share the output ?

Comment: ldd /usr/bin/apt-config also shows above error and produces following output:

Comment: linux-gate.so.1=>(hex address)    libapt-pkg.so.4.12=>/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12(hex address)     libstdc++.so.6=>/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(hex addr)  libgcc_s.so.1=>lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(hex addr)  lib.so.6=>lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(hex addr)  libutil.so.1=>/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1(hex addr)  libdl.so.2=>/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(hex addr)  slib3.so.1=>/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib3.so.1(hex addr)  libm.so.6=>lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6(hex addr)  /lib/ld-linux.so.2(hex addr)

Comment: dpkg.log file shows half-configed libc and other packages...

Comment: Have you tried a 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a' to configure the installed packages?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/users/318800/tetet yeah but it didn't do..

Answer (score 0):

There's not that much wrong. The error message essentially means that you don't have a high enough version (or different version than required) of libc6.

It means the program was compiled against glibc version 2.17, and it requires that version to run, but your system has a different version installed. You'll need to either recompile the program against the correct version of glibc that's on your system, or install a newer version of glibc (the "libc6" package in Debian).

So, you just need to upgrade your libc6 package.

To upgrade it, use these commands in the terminal:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6